# How to Receive instant notification in phonegap app for android platform that you are having new message in inbox from admin side

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova, urbanairship.com

> How to Receive instant notification in phonegap  app for android
>   platform that you are having new message in inbox from admin side
>
> I am trying to send Message from php web application to all the user
>   register to me . And After that when message is send all user must
>   receive notification of new message. I searched google and got much
>   stuff on push notification .

Can anybody tell me how to use Urban Airship PHP Library with full guide step

Any suggestion will greatly appreciated thank you .

Comment: is there any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes push notifications is the solution for you. You can use GCM from google to push notifications to apps when something interesting happens on server. You receive this and consume or fetch some data from server is your wish. There are other push services available like Urban airship, parse.com etc, but gcm is free. There multiple libraries that are in php to do the GCM calls. You have to store the gcm registration ids from the applications and push to certain users based on your logic. I dont know how to receive and consume gcm messages in phone but you can refer this [just googled](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEUQFjAB&url=http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/&ei=SH0RU-WYNIuYrgfMv4CwCA&usg=AFQjCNHP2-07YCvzaghaLVAph88tDAhaVQ&sig2=INNX9WSzwBFMBMU-PpEhmA)

Comment: firstly thanks for reply but I am registering my user from php web application and with those login credentials using this phonegap app . And according to there login credential i am posting messages from php web application. and In my application there is no need to send reply from phonegap app to web application Admin

Comment: you have to maintain do certain modifications to the phonegap app to receive push notifications. It is not mandatory to send a reply from app to server when you receive a notification. GCM can deliver data of size of 4kb max, use it. If your data is larger than 4kb, then you can just notify the user. Then app should do whatever you want upon receiving on notification

Comment: there is problem that those users who are using this app are registered with my webapplication already then how can i get there gcm registrationIds to communicate with push Notification.

Comment: Are you getting that what I mean to say.

Comment: gcm registration is not related to user registration. gcm registration is way to get an unique id that is used by google servers to deliver the message to a particular app on a particular device.

Comment: Ya I know that and according to that Id I can Send push message but my problem is that for Every user who is going to use this application need gcm registration id then how it is possible to get those Id because In My Php Web Application I am not Storing there gcm registration ids.

Comment: sir, you have to store. you have to

Comment: then how should I store those Id's and if I store those Id's then Admin must Want to send Individually seperate message to every user then how it is possible to do for 1000 of user to send single message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48753/discussion-between-abbiya-and-ricky)